# JavaScript Includes Method

Tags: javascript, dom

Could someone take a look at this and help me out? I've been working on it for a little while now and can't figure out what I'm missing.

I'm trying to set the inner HTML of a DOM element based upon the presence of a code within the message value of this response object

```js
{
  error: "{\"code\":-1121,\"msg\":\"Invalid symbol.\"}"
  message: "400 - \"{\\\"code\\\":-1121,\\\"msg\\\":\\\"Invalid symbol.\\\"}\""
  name: "StatusCodeError"
  statusCode: 400
}
```

```js
const data = await res.json();
if (data.statusCode == 400) {
  let parsedData = data.toString();
  if (parsedData.includes('1121')) {
    statusMessage.className = 'alert alert-danger text-center err-message';
    statusMessage.innerHTML = 'Invalid symbol.'

  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: A much easier way to check this is to say `if (data.error.code === 1121) { /*  do stuff */} `

Comment: @VLAZ the statusMessage element isn't updating although the condition is met but instead defaulting to the else statement (which I forgot to include in the snippet). Regardless, I'm not sure I am using the includes method correctly.

Comment: @user2079164 "*although the condition is met*" how do you know it is? Have you tried logging anything? Or debugging? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: Does mhodges'  comment work for you?

Comment: @user2079164 Please [edit] your question to include a full explanation of the problem.

Comment: @mhodges `data.error.code` is undefined because `data.error` is a string.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey `JSON.parse(data.error)`

Comment: @VLAZ  I know it _isn't_ being met because otherwise I wouldn't be here asking for help. I will try to semantically align my comments closer to your preference in the future. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @user2079164 the condition being met and an update not happening is *different* to a condition not being met therefore no update is happening. The first means that the `if` check succeeds and the code inside it doesn't work. The second means the `if` check doesn't succeed, so it's the check that fails. Crucial difference. With this in mind *basic debugging* would be to check why `parsedData.includes('1121')` produces unexpected result. Which would lead to checking `parsedData` and the problem becomes immediately apparent. Even a simple `console.log(parsedData)` would have sufficed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.error` is JSON, you should parse it and then check the `code` property.

```js
const data = await res.json();
if (data.statusCode == 400) {
  let error = JSON.parse(data.error);
  if (error.code == -1121) {
    statusMessage.className = 'alert alert-danger text-center err-message';
    statusMessage.innerHTML = error.msg;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you parsed the data transform it to JSON format.

```js
let parsedData = JSON.parse(data.error);
```

Check for a specific property `code` by using *dot notation*

```js
if(parsedData.code === -1121))
```

Comment: Calling `toString` on an object won't give you JSON

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that just meant `data.error` not `data.toString()`, check the __UPDATE__

Answer (score -1):

The parsedData checked should be the message not the whole data

```js
var data={
  error: "{\"code\":-1121,\"msg\":\"Invalid symbol.\"}",
  message: "400 - \"{\\\"code\\\":-1121,\\\"msg\\\":\\\"Invalid symbol.\\\"}\"",
  name: "StatusCodeError",
  statusCode: 400,
}


if (data.statusCode == 400) {
  let parsedData = data.message.toString();
  if (parsedData.includes('1121')) {
   console.log('alert alert-danger text-center err-message');
    console.log('Invalid symbol.')}
  }
```

Comment: That is because he hasn't posted full code and you are trying to run it inside a snippet